# Android FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume() resuming fragments out of order

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am hitting a very strange problem in Android and I can't figure out why it's happening or how to code around it.  I truly believe this to be an Android bug.

I have a MainActivity which contains a FrameLayout named main_container (its height and width are both match_parent as each fragment should be the only fragment "showing" to the user).  From MainActivity, I add Fragment A like so:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.main_container, frag, fragTag)
        .commit();
```

From there, Fragment A, upon a user's click of a view, will add Fragment B like so ("frag" and "fragTag" are different values than the above code snippet):

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_out_right)
        .add(R.id.main_container, frag, fragTag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

And from here, Fragment B will add Fragment C like so (again, "frag" and "fragTag" are different values than the previous two snippets):

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_out_right)
        .add(R.id.main_container, frag, fragTag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

So at this point, in the backstack, we should have Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C.

Fragment C invokes the MediaPicker upon the user's click of a view.  Doing so calls all fragments' onPause methods and the app is put in the background.  Now when the user selects an image, the application is resumed but here's where the bug happens... it resumes in this order, as proven with breakpoints in each fragments' onResume method:

Fragment A -> Fragment C -> Fragment B

This causes all sorts of issues because each of my fragments registers itself as a listener in the MainActivity to handle back button clicks.  This logic relies on that ordering being correct.  For some reason, it's still showing Fragment C on top, but onResume was definitely called out of order.

Perhaps even worse though... rather than clicking for MediaPicker, you can simply rotate the phone to cause a config change.  This exhibits the same behavior of reordering to A -> C -> B but in this case it DOES actually show the wrong fragment on top.  It SHOWS Fragment B on top.

Is it a design point that you can't rely on Android to resume fragments in the same order you added them to the backstack and I'm supposed to code around it?  Or am I doing something wrong?  Or is this really an Android bug?  I am by far not a newbie to Android development, but this one has me stumped.

**EDIT:**

I've pinpointed what is going on and apparently it's by design.  It seems pretty crazy to me and I disagree with the logic behind it.  I may be able to fix this with reflection, but I don't like doing that.  Anyways, on to the problem.

The problem is with the way FragmentManagerImpl keeps track of active fragments.  It has an [ArrayList](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#L424) to keep track of active fragments and when everything is paused (such as in my case where I'm starting an intent to get a photo from media gallery, thus it's leaving my app), upon resuming back into my app, it moves the fragments back to active in the [same order](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#L1123) they're in that ArrayList.  Sounds great, eh?

Well here's my problem.  When things are taken OUT of that ArrayList, they don't remove() the item, they just set it to null and then have logic to reuse that empty "slot" (line 1168 in the github link) when the next fragment comes along.  In my case, the transient fragment that leaves a hole in the ArrayList is a DialogFragment.  Putting it back into terms of my original report, Fragment A shows a DialogFragment... clicking a certain button in that DialogFragment brings up Fragment B.  Clicking another view in Fragment B brings up Fragment C.  But here's what happens to the ArrayList FragmentManagerImpl keeps track of after clicking the button in the DialogFragment:

{ FragA, null (used to be DialogFragment), FragB }

So apparently DialogFragment was moved out of active state after FragB was moved to active, thus leaving a hole.  So now we click the view in FragB to bring up FragC and the ArrayList looks like so:

{ FragA, FragC (reused DialogFragment's slot), FragB }

We go off to the media picker, come back, and voila the fragments are resumed out of order with respect to how I instantiated them in the first place.  This makes no sense to me and if you don't step into OS code with breakpoints, you never figure out why Android is not behaving the way you told it to.  Seems like it would have been easier to just do an ArrayList.remove() of the fragment you removed, thus leaving no holes.

Like I said, I can probably get around this with reflection... but I'm leery of that because there is also this mIndex variable in all Fragments that corresponds to the index of it's slot in that ArrayList (mActive).  So I'd have to be sure to keep those in sync... and now I have a dependency on knowing how the OS code works. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  Google "android fragment reordering" and you will get a whole page of links on the subject including some solutions.

Comment: Most of what I get from that search is how to reorder your backstack.  I DON'T want it reordered.  I've actually pinpointed what is going on so I'm going to edit my question with that info.